# Filter/copy a vector based on elements in another vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std

I have a vector of elements of some type (with a `name` member), and I want to filter (or copy) this vector so that it contains only the elements whose name matches a list of certain names. So basically: "Copy the element if its name is equal to any of the names in `vector<string> filter`".

I've been trying stuff with `std::copy_if` and `std::any_of`, that resulted in code like below, but I couldn't get it to work, for once because `any_of` can't be applied in this way, and I'm unsure of what the correct tools are in this case.

```
using namespace std;

template<class T>
struct MyType {
  string name;
  T data;
};

template<class T>
vector<MyType<T>> filter(vector<MyType<T>> items, vector<string> filter)
{
  vector<MyType<T>> filteredItems;
  copy_if(begin(items), end(items), begin(filteredItems), any_of(begin(filter), end(filter), [](const MyType<T>& lhs, const MyType<T>& rhs) {return lhs.name == rhs.name; }));
  return filteredItems;
};

int main() {
  vector<MyType<int>> items { {"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 3} };
  vector<string> filter { "a", "c" };
  auto filteredItems = filter(items, filter);
}
```

How can I accomplish this, preferably with `std::` functionality? (C++11/14 welcome)

[Above code on ideone if you want to play around.](http://ideone.com/ptRZDy)

I guess this might be a good example to use ranges, but my code needs to compile on VS 2013 so I can't use https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3 and I'm a bit hesitant to use an older ranges library, but I could be convinced otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copy_if` is the right choice, but your predicate is wrong, and you need to use `back_inserter`.

```
copy_if(begin(items), end(items), back_inserter(filteredItems), 
       [&](const MyType<T> & item) { return std::find(begin(filter), end(filter), item.name) != end(filter);} );
```

To find something in a range, use `std::find`, which performs a simple linear search. If `filter` is sorted, `std::binary_search` can be used too.

Comment: Thank you very much. Aww, I should've been able to come up with that by myself! I was too focused on `any_of` and friends, and didn't think about `find`.